# ImagePullBackOff on kubeflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, minikube, google-container-registry, kubeflow

When I tried to run kubeflow pipelines on minikube with components whose Docker images are stored in **Google Container Registry**, I got `ImagePullBackOff` error.
I already set credential according to **[Ref1](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/pipelines/authentication-pipelines/)**, by running a such following command.

```bash
kubectl create secret -n [my-namespace] generic user-gcp-sa \
  --from-file=user-gcp-sa.json=application_default_credentials.json
```

And I use `use_gcp_secret` method when defining a pipeline to use the registered credential according to [**Ref2**](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.extensions.html#module-kfp.gcp).

```py
@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name='example_pipeline')
def example_pipeline():
    example_component1_task = example_component1_op(
        input_1='/app/input.txt',
        input_2=8,
    ).apply(use_gcp_secret(secret_name='user-gcp-sa'))
    
    example_component2_task = example_component2_op(
        input_1=example_component1_task.outputs['output_1'],
        input_2=5,
    ).apply(use_gcp_secret(secret_name='user-gcp-sa'))
```

For building Docker images, I followed [**Ref3**](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/component-development/).

But after running pipeline by `create_run_from_pipeline_func` method and see `Runs>Events` section on Kubeflow dashboard, there is a message `ImagePullBackOff`.

[image]

I think [**Ref4**](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/) is irrelevant but I also tried  `minikube addons configure registry-creds` but nothing changed as expected.

There is no other clues other than the `ImagePullBackOff` message, so I ask the question here.

### Update

I found the message but I already tried all listed in [**Ref5**](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). Also I added enough role to service account and created json key from it.

```
message: >-
      Failed to pull image
      "asia.gcr.io/myproject-123456/example_component1@sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx":
      rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized:
      You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you
      may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the
      steps in:
      https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

If lack of information to answer the question, please tell me.

### References

1. [Authenticating Pipelines to Google Cloud](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/pipelines/authentication-pipelines/)
2. [kfp.gcp module](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.extensions.html#module-kfp.gcp)
3. [Building Components](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/component-development/)
4. [minikube - Registries](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/)
5. [Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)

Comment: can you check the log ? something is missing or wrong given that error and as far as i can see ur authenticating

Comment: I cannot see any [logs](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/76238346/185738312-49e66059-202d-47ca-98a3-c0a0e7a99225.png) from Logs section... I created the credential from service account at console and download it as json file.

Comment: this wont help but give it a try https://www.containiq.com/post/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff at least you are getting a good error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could not be a perfect solution but I solved the issue by doing 2 things:

- avoid to use "latest" tag
- load docker images on minikube

```bash
minikube image load image_name:tag_name  
minikube image load image_name:tag_name
```